# holoviews hv.save x label cutoff (trimmed)

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I am trying to save a holoviews plot, to png, using the bokeh backend. But the saved png has its xlabel partially cutoff. How do I increase the whitespace margin at the bottom of the plot to avoid this?

I have tried to create a single column NdLayout, and then edit the plot afterwards, but each plot has its xlabel trimmed.

When rendering this in a jupyter notebook, the xlabel appears as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
a1 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=600)
a2 = np.random.normal(1,1,size=600)
b = np.arange(0,600)
xx = hv.Curve([(ii,jj) for ii,jj in zip(b,a1)],['predicted_sample'],['Value']).relabel('StandardNormal')
yy = hv.Curve([(ii,jj) for ii,jj in zip(b,a2)],['predicted_sample'],['Value']).relabel('ShiftedNormal')
hv.save(xx*yy,"plot.png")
```

Single: [image: Single plot with trimmed xlabel]

---

```
hv.save(((xx*yy) + (xx*yy)).cols(1),'ndlayout_plots.png')
```

NdLayout:[image: NdLayout plot with trimmed xlabel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that find this, I found a work around using hooks and setting the bokeh `min_border_bottom` value directly.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv

hv.extension('bokeh')

a1 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=600)
a2 = np.random.normal(1,1,size=600)
b = np.arange(0,600)

xx = hv.Curve([(ii,jj) for ii,jj in zip(b,a1)],['predicted_sample'],['Value']).relabel('StandardNormal')
yy = hv.Curve([(ii,jj) for ii,jj in zip(b,a2)],['predicted_sample'],['Value']).relabel('ShiftedNormal')

pp = xx*yy #create the overlay

def fixBottomMargin(plot,element):
  plot.handles['plot'].min_border_bottom = 100

pp = pp.opts(opts.Curve(hooks=[fixBottomMargin])) #call the hooks on the curve element

hv.save(pp,filename='plot.png')
```

Information found by reading the bokeh documentation, [Styling Visual Attributes](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html)